# infinite loop when using useEffect with a required funcion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm developing a dashboard an making a custom hook. It's for sorting and filtering tables.

Every time that a sort or filter field has been changed, I need to refetch with new fields. So I was trying to use `useEffect` but I'm having an infinite loop because linter tells me that I have to include `onRefetch()` function

```
useEffect(() => {
    onRefetch();
  }, [onRefetch, sort]);
```

If I remove `onRefetch` from the dependencies, it works perfectly but linter fails.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Linter fails? What does it mean? Does it complain on something?

Comment: it fails because everytime react re-renders it creates a new onrefetch function, what you need to add in the dependecy array, is exactly that, the dependencies you need to calculate the next effect

Comment: We need some context, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `useCallback`?

```js
const memoizedOnRefetch = useCallback(() => onRefetch(), []);

useEffect(() => {
    memoizedOnRefetch();
  }, [memoizedOnRefetch, sort]);
```

Comment: I just wonder - whats the point of adding a function into dependency array?

Comment: It's just part of the idiom as far as I know.

Comment: If you don't add it, depending on the use case, the function can be "stale" and it can create bug hard to detect.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable eslint, because of your purpose.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    onRefetch();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [sort, filter]);
```